# jqGrid - getGridParam/getCol Issue (odd)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Been doing a custom jqgrid and 2 different method is giving me different result:

This method will give me accurate total of record IF I do a "direct" input (see &Input=1 in URL):

```
$('#1ASList').jqGrid({
    url: DateFile+'Data.php?Load=AllianceStatus&Input=1',
    datatype: 'json',
    colModel: [{name:'A',width:64,align:'left'},{name:'C',width:25,align:'right',formatter:'integer'}],
    altRows: true,
    height: 102,
    gridComplete: function(){ $('#1ASTtl').empty().html('[ '+$(this).jqGrid('getGridParam','records')+' ]'); }
});
```

This method will give me blanks and the 3rd Grid will give me total result, which I do not want.  I want each Grid to give me their own results:

```
for(var iAlliS = 0; iAlliS < 3; iAlliS++){
    $('#'+iAlliS+'ASList').jqGrid({
        url: DateFile+'Data.php?Load=AllianceStatus&Input='+iAlliS,
        datatype: 'json',
        colModel: [{name:'A',width:64,align:'left'},{name:'C',width:25,align:'right',formatter:'integer'}],
        altRows: true,
        height: 102,
        gridComplete: function(){ $('#'+iAlliS+'ASTtl').empty().html('[ '+$(this).jqGrid('getGridParam','records')+' ]'); }
    });
}
```

Why do both give me different result?  What am I missing here?  (I am not using FooterData, all custom results)

Comment: Are you sure that you want your grid nums from 0 to 2? i mean your for loop `for(var iAlliS = 0; iAlliS < 3; iAlliS++)`. If So can you show what kind of requests sends to server? In Chrome `F12` -> `Network`. I think you get what's wrong right away.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/5miflu

As you can see in image, friend(grid 0) is null, shows 0, neutral(grid 1) supposed to show 13, hostile(grid 2) is supposed to show 64 and reds is supposed to show [ 0 ], it works if i do it the 'individual' as coded above.  But instead with the for() loop, it gives me the total on the 4th grid Reds(grid 3).  So question is, what is wrong with my for() loop?

Comment: the F12 on Chrome is showing me that I'm pulling ajax properly, its the grid placement is done properly, only issue I am having are the TOTAL of record count placing in the wrong "title"

Comment: could be that this is where your problem is. Change `$(this).jqGrid('getGridParam','records')` with `$('#'+iAlliS+'ASList').jqGrid('getGridParam','records')`

Comment: Tried, gave me an undefined.

Comment: can i clearify, you setting records num with this string? `$('#'+iAlliS+'ASTtl').empty().html('[ '+$(this).jqGrid('getGridParam','records')+' ]');`
I just can't see whole picture. Do you have container with `id` like `0ASTtl` and what is your container for grid? Isn't it have the same id? Can you show your html?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/5miv2c  This is correct if done individually on first code.

My HTML shows like:

<div><span id='ASTtl0'>[ - ]</span> Friend</div>
<div><table id='ASList0'></table></div>
<div><span id='ASTtl1'>[ - ]</span> Neutral</div>
<div><table id='ASList1'></table></div>

It's doing it all correctly, just putting the result in the wrong column (4th)

Comment: ignore the number I have in the HTML, I was trying every avenue, thinking ID hates number in the beginning, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's try this. Instead of using `gridComplete` event of `jqgrid` use `loadComplete` it has one parameter `data` which has full data from the server. So you can change your code like this:

```
for(var iAlliS = 0; iAlliS < 3; iAlliS++){
    $('#'+iAlliS+'ASList').jqGrid({
        url: DateFile+'Data.php?Load=AllianceStatus&Input='+iAlliS,
        datatype: 'json',
        colModel: [{name:'A',width:64,align:'left'},{name:'C',width:25,align:'right',formatter:'integer'}],
        altRows: true,
        height: 102,
        loadComplete: function(data){ $('#'+iAlliS+'ASTtl').empty().html('[ '+data.records+' ]'); }
    });
}
```

So you should not have any more problem to get data from `DOM` and get it directly from `JSON` that comes from server.